# pexpect - how to pass in password using events

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, pexpect

In this snipper I'm trying to pass the password as an event, why does the following not work?

```
 password = input("INPUT PASSWORD: ")
 pexpect.run("ssh -lX user@gmail.com 'ls -l'",
 events={'(?i)password':' \n'}, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples provided by the [documentation](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/run.html?highlight=events) for pexpect, it looks like you should be passing the password on as part of the value of `'(?i)password'`.

```
from pexpect import *
run('scp foo user@example.com:.', events={'(?i)password': mypassword})
```

In your case this would translate to this.

```
pexpect.run(
    "ssh -lX eandersson@my-server.com 'ls -l'",
    events={'(?i)password': '%s\n' % password}
)
```

A more complete example using getpass to hide the password would look like this.

```
import pexpect
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
print pexpect.run(
    "ssh -lX eandersson@10.0.1.1 'ls -l'",
    events={'(?i)password': '%s\n' % password}
)
```